# Firebase send server notification java

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I saw this question using [Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228558/how-to-use-firebase-rest-api-in-java). But still didn't figure out how to send a simple push notification from my server to topic subscribed users.
I don't understand what's wrong in my request as I am trying to build based on [their examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

```
public class OverSLANotifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, FirebaseException {
        String rawData = "{\"to\": \"/topics/sla\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is test push notification!\",}}";
        String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(rawData, "UTF-8");

        URL u = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=AI<redacted>VGB6YwPWrinoz1YFBgdKv4Pgm8s");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(encodedData.getBytes());
        System.out.println(""+ conn.getResponseCode() + "-->>"+conn.getResponseMessage());
    }
```

My client is [properly set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?utm_source=studio) and can receive if I send from console.

The response is always:

> 401-->>Unauthorized

Answer (score 1):

you're json seems invalid:

```
{\"to\": \"/topics/sla\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is test push notification!\",}}
```

vs

```
{\"to\": \"/topics/sla\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is test push notification!\"}}
```

Also check the documentation:

> The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated.
>   Possible causes are:

- **Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request**.
- Invalid project number sent as key.
- Key valid but with FCM service disabled.
- Request originated from a server not whitelisted
  in the Server key IPs.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

PS: its also invalid in the documentation youll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) ;)